# extract characters from filename of newest file

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a bash script where i will need to check a directory for existing files and look at the last 4 digits of the first segment of the file name to set the counter when adding new files to the directory.

Naming Scructure:

```
yymmddHNAZXLCOM0001.835
```

I need to put the portion in the example 0001 into a CTR variable so the next file it puts into the directory will be

```
yymmddHNAZXLCOM0002.835
```

and so on.

what would be the easiest and shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `sed`:

```
filename="yymmddHNAZXLCOM0001.835"
first_part=$(echo $filename | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\([0-9]\{4,4\}\)\.\(.*\)/\1/')
counter=$(echo $filename | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\([0-9]\{4,4\}\)\.\(.*\)/\2/')
suffix=$(echo $filename | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\([0-9]\{4,4\}\)\.\(.*\)/\3/')
echo "$first_part$(printf "%04u" $(($counter + 1))).$suffix"
=> "yymmddHNAZXLCOM0002.835"
```

All three `sed` calls use the same regular expression.  The only thing that changes is the group selected to return.  There's probably a way to do all of that in one call, but my `sed`-fu is rusty.

Alternate version, using a Bash array:

```
filename="yymmddHNAZXLCOM0001.835"
ary=($(echo $filename | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\([0-9]\{4,4\}\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3/'))
echo "${ary[0]}$(printf "%04u" $((${ary[1]} + 1))).${ary[2]}"
=> "yymmddHNAZXLCOM0002.835"
```

Note: This version assumes that the filename does not have spaces in it.

Comment: Will this work if the yymmdd part of the file name and the 0001 part always change depending on what the newest file is with that naming convention?

Comment: @camarokris- The regular expressions key off of four consecutive digits that are immediately followed by a dot, so numbers in the filename shouldn't pose a problem.  There would only be a problem if you also have dots in your filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
current=`echo yymmddHNAZXLCOM0001.835 | cut -d . -f 1 | rev | cut -c 1-4 | rev`
next=`echo $current | awk '{printf("%04i",$0+1)}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f() {
    if [[ $1 =~ (.*)([[:digit:]]{4})(\.[^.]*)$ ]]; then
        local -a ctr=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")
        touch "${ctr}$((++ctr[1]))${ctr[2]}"
        # ...
    else
        echo 'no matches'
    fi
}

shopt -s nullglob
f *
```